# Texturing Bricks and Applying Them

Tags: texturing, shape-keys, color

I have a blender project that I need to complete and here's what I want to achieve. I need to copy a group of bricks so that they are opposite each other and I want to texture them blue. I would like to know the simplest method to copy all the bricks and paste them to the other side and texture them.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are looking for here. Could you add more detail (e.g., screenshots) to your question?

Comment: Do want to texture ALL bricks blue or just the copies? do you need to manipulate the copies in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a mirror modifier. If that's not working, you have a couple options:

1. Make sure you're mirroring on the right axis.

[image]

2. Make sure your object is centered. push shift+s> select "cursor to center." Then, in the tools panel (object mode) go to "set origin">"Origin to 3d cursor."

If you don't want to use a mirror modifier, you can select the object and push shift+d to duplicate it, then move it where you want.

As far as texturing goes, that really depends on what exactly you want done. I'd recommend doing a google search for BlenderGuru's texturing videos, I'm sure you will find them insightful.